# Error attempt to index a nil value (upvalue "cfg)

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

I was moving some map files, and I rebooted my server (FiveM) and when I called it again it started to give this problem, I undo everything I did, I put the old files again, but the error kept happening. And I do not know what to do to solve it.

I threw all the changed files back to normal, but it did not solve anything.

```
local cfg = module("cfg/blips_markers")

-- add additional static blips/markers
AddEventHandler("vRP:playerSpawn",function(user_id, source, first_spawn)
  if first_spawn then
    for k,v in pairs(cfg.blips) do
      vRPclient.addBlip(source,{v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6]})
    end

    for k,v in pairs(cfg.markers) do
      vRPclient.addMarker(source,{v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10],v[11]})
    end
  end
end)
```

Inside the server the blip_markes are gone and some player data too, because of that.

Comment: Please provide steps and code to reproduce this error.

Comment: `module("cfg/blips_markers")` returns `nil`.  Does the module exist?

Answer (score 0):

A quick debug would be to assign cfg the value of an integer, if your problem solves, you know that something is wrong with `module("cfg/blips_markers")`. However, please provide the code associated with `module("cfg/blips_markers")`.